Update a Column Value Whenever an Update is Run Against a Temporal Table
Say I have a temporal table that has a column IsReadyForStuff of datatype bit, and another column OrderDate.
I would like to add a trigger to my temporal table that when OrderDate is updated also sets IsReadyForStuff to 0.
Normally I would use an INSTEAD OF trigger for that, but temporal tables don't support INSTEAD OF triggers.
Is there a way to do what I want?
NOTE: I tried using an after trigger, but the original update of the OrderDate was already made. So it made an entry in the history table for that, then also made an entry for setting IsReadyForStuff set to false (in the current table).
I really need them to be in the same entry.
NOTE 2: Ideally, I would update that application that is making this change, but it is a total hot mess, and edits to that application will not be possible for this.

for that you would use a BEFORE UPDATE trigger

@nbk - Sadly, BEFORE triggers are not a thing in SQL Server

Uh, i dunno, rename the table and create a view with same name, and add instead of trigger on that view? It will add to the mess though, not make it less. What's the purpose of "IsReadyForStuff"? Can some other solution be used to figure out of it's ready or not

This sounds a bit like an XY Problem. The IsReadyForStuff column sounds a bit suspect from a design perspective. If you simply can't fix the database design then the next best would be a change to the app...but that isn't possible either. Sounds like your double entry in the history table is about the best you can do with the limitations in place.

How about adding a column StuffLastDoneDate (in the same or a separate table). Whenever it differs from OrderDate (or is null), that is the equivalent of having IsReadyForStuff = 1. Once the do-stuff process is complete, you can update StuffLastDoneDate to match - the equivalent of setting IsReadyForStuff = 0. You could even define a computed column for having IsReadyForStuff. (Caution - A potential race condition might exist, if the process that handles and resets the IsReadyForStuff condition runs in parallel with a process that "creates more stuff".)

Store the flag value in a variable before inserting the statement.
Add in the same SP where you have inserted the script for a specific table

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
